# Transmitting and receiving on GNURadio osmocom

Tags: gnuradio, transmission, gnuradio-companion, software-defined-radio

I want to transmit QPSK modulated signal and simply receive it  simultaneously to a file using SDR platform (Bladrfx40), but no output shows on  received side.

Here is the flow graph I implemented:
[image: Flow Graph]

Here is what I want to receive and what is being transmitted:
[image: fft transmit]

Here is what I actually receive:
[image: fft receive]

Constellation plot on transmitter side:
[image]

Constellation plot on receiver side:
[image]
Zoomed Constellation on receiver side [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvOOb.png)
Can i know where i am lacking in my procedure?

Comment: soooo first of all, I still have to say that more than 5 years after we announced it (it's getting tiresome): GNU Radio will remove the WX components from the upcoming release. Do not build new flowgraphs with WX GUI – use Qt GUI instead, it's faster and unlike WX we can still maintain it. Also, Packet encoder and Packet decoder are both in the **deprecated** category for a reason – they have bugs that can't be fixed. Please don't use them.

Comment: So, it's not quite clear what your problem with the reception is. This looks fine to me. Can you explain how this differs from what you were expecting?

Comment: The receiver side output is not exactly i am transmitting, since the constellation plot has a lot of difference ( shown in the post)

Comment: Also, i have changed WX to QT and removed packet encoder. The constellation plot shown in the post is after making these changes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how it has "a lot of difference": Can you put how you think the spectra differ into words? I'm not doing this to annoy you, I just don't understand what you're expecting!

Comment: Constellation plot i am talking about. It should be dotted spheres at four different ends.

Comment: well, you've forgotten to zoom in on that, so I can't really make a statement there!

Comment: I had zoomed it, it was nothing like that. Post edited with the zoomed version.

Comment: ah, this looks like you've got insufficient receive gain, so that your values are quantized. Also, doesn't look like you have any phase synchronization?

Comment: How to achieve that? Is the problem of gain only or what?

Comment: um, as I said, at least gain, and lack  of phase sync.